# Injecting Mouse Listener not working using ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

So here i am trying to inject my Mouse Listener class into this other class so i can do things with it. Below are my classes...

This is my first class: THE class in which i want to inject my own listener into

```
package testing;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class MouseListenerTest extends Applet implements java.awt.event.MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, FocusListener
{
    private String field;
    private int num;      //Just some fields why not
    private int test;

    /*
     * OTher methods and fields and stuff just generated for testing
     *
     */

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        //doStuff

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        //doStuff

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        //doStuff

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        //doStuff

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        //doStuff

    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        //doStuff

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        //doStuff

    }
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

This is my class that i made which is going to be used to override that classes mouselistener

```
    package testing;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;


public abstract class MouseListener extends FocusListener implements java.awt.event.MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public abstract void _mouseClicked(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent);

    public abstract void _mouseDragged(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent);

    public abstract void _mouseEntered(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent);

    public abstract void _mouseExited(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent);

    public abstract void _mouseMoved(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent);

    public abstract void _mousePressed(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent);

    public abstract void _mouseReleased(MouseEvent paramMouseEvent);

    public abstract void _mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent paramMouseEvent);

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        _mouseDragged(e);
        e.consume();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        _mouseMoved(e);
        e.consume();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        _mouseClicked(e);
        e.consume();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        _mouseEntered(e);
        e.consume();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        _mouseExited(e);
        e.consume();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        x++;
        y++;
        _mousePressed(e);
        e.consume();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        _mouseReleased(e);
        e.consume();
    }

}
```

And this is the class i am using to change the fields and methods. (NOTICE i just included a frame for it. This isn't actually how i am doing it. (with this class that is) i load the class and `.accept(cn, ...)` somewhere else where i pass it into this class)

```
package testing;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.AbstractInsnNode;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodInsnNode;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode;

public class Injector
{

    public static ClassNode getClassNode()
    {return new ClassNode(Opcodes.ASM5);}

    public static ClassNode transformClass(ClassNode cn)
    {
        List<MethodNode> a = cn.methods;
        for(MethodNode mn : a)
        {
            if(mn.name.startsWith("mouse"))
            {
                ClassNode superClass = getClassNode(); //loaded the classNode just there for emphasis
                if(superClass!=null && !superClass.superName.equals("testing/MouseListener"))
                {
                    superClass.superName="testing/MouseListener";
                    System.out.println("Changed superclass of : "+superClass.name+" = "+superClass.superName);
                    List<MethodNode> c = superClass.methods;
                    for (MethodNode node : c)
                    {
                        if (node.name.equals("<init>"))
                        {
                            ListIterator<AbstractInsnNode> ili = node.instructions.iterator();
                            while (ili.hasNext())
                            {
                                AbstractInsnNode ain = ili.next();
                                if (ain.getOpcode() == Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL)
                                {
                                    MethodInsnNode min = (MethodInsnNode) ain;
                                    if (min.owner.equals("java/lang/Object"))
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("Changed initialization owner.");
                                        min.owner = "testing/MouseListener";
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                mn.name="_"+mn.name;
                System.out.println("Hooked method : "+mn.name);
            }
        }
        return cn;
    }
}
```

Now here comes the actual question and problem that i am having:

1. The injector works semi-properly it changes the methods names to the abstract ones in my Mouse Listener as it should but here comes the problem
2. It does not change the IMPORTS on top so that therefore it knows that it is mine. This causes the program that i am injecting to throw a bunch of AbstractErrors as it does not override all the methods of Mouse Listener because i changed them.

My question is does anyone know or can point me in the right direction on how to get the imports to change? so it would look like "testing.MouseListener" and etc..

Comment: Manually remove the MouseListener imports?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I am loading this from a class file that is in a jarfile. I could do that i guess but i would like to find some way to do it

Comment: What do you mean by "does not change the imports"? Imports do not exist in a .class file. All references in a .class file refer to specific fully-qualified names of classes and methods.

Comment: @yole actually yes i just noticed that sorry i was using a bytecode viewer and was looking at the decompiled version. but netherless it does not change the `implements java.awt.event.(listener)`

Comment: Why do you expect a change in the `implements java.awt.event.(listener)` clause? According to what you have posted, both classes implement the `java.awt.event.MouseListener` and `java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener` interface and you are not doing anything to change it. But your code is inconsistent, a `class MouseListener extends FocusListener` should not compile and your transformation is assuming that the class to transform is a subclass of `Object` whereas it’s actually a subclass of `Applet` and that such a drastic change in the type hierarchy will cause problems, comes at no surprise.

Comment: @Holger Yes thanks for the advice. I did realize i wasn't really doing anything to change the interfaces and the Mouse listener was wrong. I have it working now but there seems to be a problem when loading the classes as it throws an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class` I looked up why and understand why it is doing it because i changed the class but do you have any tips on how to get around this? I don't have the source code so i can't just simply recompile again or anything of that nature

Comment: That error tells you that the class is implementing a type that is actually a `class` instead of an `interface`. It’s hard to help you when your posted code doesn’t match what you’re actually doing…

Comment: @Holger Sorry it is a bunch of code to post. It is injection for making a BotClient for Runescape... Trying to inject my own mouseListener into the client.  But that does help a lot thanks